# How do I iterate over (and make changes to) a collection that is the value of another collection

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

I have a map that maps bytes to sets of bytes.  I want to walk through the map and make changes to the set.

```
private HashMap<Byte, HashSet<Byte>> table;
...
Iterator<Entry<Byte, HashSet<Byte>>> it = table.entrySet().iterator();
while( it.hasNext() ) {
   Map.Entry<Byte, HashSet<Byte>> pairs = it.next();
   byte node = pairs.getKey();
   HashSet<Byte> hSet = pairs.getValue();
   Iterator<Byte> setIter = hSet.iterator();
   while( setIter.hasNext() ) {
      byte sNode = setIter.next();  // Throws a ConcurrentModificationException
      ...
   }
 }
```

This code throws a ConcurrentModificationException when I try to iterate through the sub iterator.  What should I do to iterate through, and make changes to, this collection within my map?

Comment: What kind of changes you want to make?

Comment: You might be better off with a [Guava `HashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html).

Comment: Tried simulating your problem.But code is working perfectly fine for me.Can you post any additional details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get the exception because you modify the set during the iteration (in the lines that were not included into the question). The "fail-fast" iterators are throwing it, if they detect that the structure of the collection has been changed.

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

If you are only deleting from the set while you iterate it, you can **use the remove method of the iterator** instead of the Set methods. If you also want to add to the set while iterating, you need to create a copy of the Set, and iterate that (but this case is unlikely, you can add to a set without iterating it...)

Comment: +1 for indicating that the problem is not caused by the line that throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```
for(Byte node : table.keySet()) {
   HashSet<Byte> hSet = table.get(node);
   Iterator<Byte> setIter = hSet.iterator();
   while( setIter.hasNext() ) {
      byte sNode = setIter.next(); 
      ...
   }
 }
```

If you want to modify the `hSet` your best approach might be to loop over a copy of the `Set` :

```
for(Byte node : table.keySet()) {
    HashSet<Byte> hSet = table.get(node);

    for (Byte sNode : new HashSet<Byte>(hSet)) {
        //do things which modifies the original hSet
    }
}
```